# Expression denotes a type where a variable, value is expected error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the colour of some materials in unity with the following code:

```
    public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>();
public string name;
public Color setToColor = Color.white;

public Color ChangeObjectMaterialColour()
{

    foreach(GameObject t in targets)
        if(t.renderer != null)
        {
            if(t.renderer.materials != null)
            {
                foreach(Material m in t.renderer.materials)
                    if(m.name.Equals(name))
                        m.color = setToColor;

            }
        }

    return Color;
}
```

The should take in a list of object I want to change the colour of (which I'll store in the list) and change it to the colour I specifiy. This code is stored in a serpeate class.

Then in my other class where I'm calling this method I'm doing as follows:

```
private ChangeObjectColour colour;

if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour1")
{           
    hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = colour.ChangeObjectMaterialColour();
}
```

However this has resulted in the following error:

> Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

When I click on it, Unity takes me to `return Color;`at the end of my first method.

How can I defeat this bug?

Comment: As a side note, having `Color`, `ChangeObjectColour`, `setToColor`, `colour`, `m.color`, `"Colour1"` and `ChangeObjectMaterialColour` all in the same space is... rather discombobulating. Even as a UK English speaker, I have to accept: when it comes to programming, "color" (no "u") is the convention.

Comment: Yeah I know sorry, I'll change that up. Force of habit at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed:

```
return Color;
```

what `Color` did you intend to return? Should this be `return setToColor;` ? or maybe the entire method should be `void` and not `return` *anything*...